# How to keep Cordova app in background (iOS, Android, WP, BlackBerry)?

Tags: cordova

I'm working on a simple Cordova app that get news feed from specific website that users can view these news through the app.

The question is, How can I implement the following scenario:
when any new feeds posted in the website, I want to notify the mobile devices that a new feed is here while the app is not in foreground or even closed.

Note: I'm not a native mobile apps developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should learn about [push notifications](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)

Comment: @Marchin, is this works when the app is closed or not in the foreground?

Comment: yes, thats main purpose of push notifications. you get the notification on status bar and by tapping on it, your application will turn on.